# Mapping multiple database tables to one object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy and MySQL to create an ORM.
I automapped my database tables with this:

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
tScenario = Base.classes.table_scenario
tSchedule = Base.classes.table_schedule
tScheduleRestriction = Base.classes.table_schedule_restriction
```

Scenarios have schedules, which have restrictions.
Then at some point I create this object:

```
schedule = (session
   .query(tSchedule)
   .join(tScheduleRestriction)
   .filter(and_(
      tSchedule.scenario_id==47, 
      tSchedule.period=='saturday')
      )
   .all()
)
```

I can access all the *table_schedule* columns and set them normally, like this:

```
schedule[1].parameter01 = 19
```

But if I want to access a column from the joined table (*table_schedule_restriction*), it's buried in that thing:

```
schedule[1].table_schedule_restriction_collection[0].parameter01_min = 20
```

My question is: **how can I get all the columns from both tables as direct properties of my schedule object**?

I know one way is to declare all the columns from both tables inside the .query, like this pseudocode:

".query(**tSchedule.parameter01, tScheduleRestriction.parameter01_min**, etc)"

But I think there is a better way.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: I'd suggest making a view and querying from that

Comment: I'm new to SQLAlchemy, could you elaborate?

Comment: A view actually isn't a SQLAlchemy thing, it's a database thing. You can learn more by searching about database views. A view is a virtual table that you can define in SQL. So you can organize the data the way you want there and then bring it into Python. It's often cleaner than using an ORM for something like this